# What spreadsheet programs are available?

Tags: openoffice.org, productivity

I want to know if there are any other spreadsheet programs besides OpenOffice.org Calc.

Comment: - calligra https://calligra.org/ - gnumeric http://www.gnumeric.org/ - sc https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10699 - kspread - pyspread https://pyspread.gitlab.io/

Answer (score 11):

### Gnumeric

Gnumeric is part of 'GNOME Office' suite, which means it stylistically fits into Ubuntu, but can just as easily be used on its own.

To install Gnumeric in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gnumeric
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently this does not open `*.xls` files.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/

Answer (score 3):

For text-only use in a terminal, there's [`sc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/sc) ([`man` page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/sc.1.html)).
If the first link is not working, you can try the [Ubuntu Packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sc).

Also for text terminals, Lotus 1-2-3 for Unix has been [ported](https://github.com/taviso/123elf) to Linux.

Comment: `sc`: "sc: the Venerable Spreadsheet Calculator" (how to): https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10699

Answer (score 2):

Check these out... here is list of all spreadsheet software for linux... :)

http://www.linuxlinks.com/Software/Spreadsheets/

else u can try koffice, staroffice and gnome-office.

I hope this helped.. :)

Comment: Star Office is Sun's commercial version of OpenOffice.org (basically OpenOffice.org with different branding and some commercial clipart, fonts, templates & maybe extra language tools added).

Comment: yeah i mentioned it because its compatible with linux.. :)

Comment: Grab Libreoffice Calc

Answer (score 2):

For large spreadsheets, **Gnumeric** is the way to go!  Libreoffice is too slow for plotting graphs with large multi-column datasets, but gnumeric handles them far better with high responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Chinese clone of MS Office, called [WPS Office](http://www.wps.com/). It offers both ribbon and toolbar-based user interfaces, which you can switch on the fly. It is not open source, though.

[image: The three basic WPS Office apps]

For more details and installation instructions, [see this *OMG! Ubuntu!* article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/wps-office-for-linux-looks-like-microsoft-office-but-isnt).